# Spring: Accessed parameters from HttpServletRequest return null

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I've got a POST method in my controller that should create a new Object from an AJAX POST.

I created a factory method that will populate the object from an `HttpServletRequest`. However, when submitting the request, the factory method fails because of a `NullPointerException` while processing the parameters from the request object.

I have looked into several posts on Stackoverflow and can't seem to find something wrong with my code. The usual suggestion seems to be that I just have to add a `HttpServletRequest` into my signature, and that Spring would automatically wire that object.

It does actually create a request object, but the created request does not contain any parameters.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/lead")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "ch.company.app.backend" })
public class EventLeadController {
  @Autowired
  EventLeadRepository leadRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  public void saveLead(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Country: " + request.getParameter("country")); // returns "Country: null"
    EventLeadFactory leadFactory = new EventLeadFactory();

    EventLead lead = leadFactory.createFromHttpServletRequest(request);

    leadRepository.save(lead);
  };
}
```

Comment: You'll need to include the (javascript?) code which constructs the POST

Comment: have you tried public void saveLead(@RequestBody ModelClass model)  ??

Comment: @AmitMishra That would mean that I no longer need the Factory class, right? Instead I would have to make a JSON request that maps to an actual Java class, or do I misinterpret something? Is there anyway to directly access the `HttpServletRequest` of the current request?

Comment: yes as long as parameter name matches with model variables you should be good to go. By the way any specific reason u want to access HttpServletRequest ?? as if it only about accessing parameter what i mentioned above should be more then enough

Comment: No not really, I just had created a factory class that creates the object from a Servlet request (that's how I used to do it in a earlier version). Guess that'll do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `@RequestBody` annotation.
Example:

```
public void saveLead(@RequestBody Model model)
```

Comment: If I do that I get a `400 Bad Request`. Am I right in assuming that I'd have to specify my `EventLead` object in the method signature, instead of the `HttpServletRequest`?

Comment: Yes it will create the json request you are sending from the client to java object if you do so.